# Jquery ajax whitespace and ampersand issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, encoding, character-encoding

I am doing something like this

```
var apiOptions = {
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: "GET",
    success: success
};

if(dataOptions) {
    apiOptions.data = {
        key: self.settings.key,
        limit: self.limit,
        address: dataOptions.address,
    };
}
$.ajax(apiOptions);
```

And it works fine for everything except for when I have " & ", so spaces around an ampersand. So the request parameter looks like `"D+&+D,+enterprisess"` or `D+%26+D%2C`. This then returns a 404 on the server.

Any idea what to do here ?

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent()` to URL encode your values.

Comment: From what I read passing in my parameters in the jquery ajax call I shouldn't have to. Also I tried it and it breaks it even worse I think it does like double encoding then

Comment: Funnily enough it works on my local server i.e. parameter like "D+%26+D%2C" but not on development server

Comment: From the look of that you are indeed double-encoding it. What does the value look like before you put it in the object?

Comment: Just normal i.e. "D & D,"

Comment: So basically locally I have a URL like http://localhost/blah/2.0/moreblah?callback=jQuery111206357761636261035_1444035031102&address=D+%26+D%2C+enterprisess and it works but if I try the same url on my development server this request throws a 404

Comment: Please try POST instead of GET or use html encode function before sending data

Comment: It's a GET webservice I am calling, so I can't change that

Comment: I would need more code to help you, but as quick workaround I would try url.replace(' ', '%20'), what server are you using? and what browser?

Comment: Have you tried adding the arguments directly to the url as a query parameter?

Comment: Guys, I think you are using the wrong JS fuction, for white spaces in URL, you should use encodeURI(). encodeURIComponent is for something else entirely, primarily to handle XML stuff.

Answer (score 2):

For pass parameters with space and speacial character in ajax, you have use escape and unescape function.

```
var test = 'Exemplae Actão ç @#$%$ ';
var testEscape = escape(test);
console.info(test , testEscape ,  unescape(testEscape ));
```

This solve you problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp()` `/\s(&)\s/`

```js
var data = "123 & abc";
var res = data.replace(/\s(&)\s/, "$1");
console.log("data:", data,"res:", res)
```